# Mahapps Message Dialogs

Tags: mahapps.metro

I would like to know how to create Messages Dialogs in Mahapps. All the examples i've found were about clicking a button, but i need to create the Message from inside code (in the middle of a Try in a static async i.e.).

So... this is the code behind the MainWindow (From the GIT examples)

```
 public async void ShowMessageDialog(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // This demo runs on .Net 4.0, but we're using the Microsoft.Bcl.Async package so we have async/await support
        // The package is only used by the demo and not a dependency of the library!
        var mySettings = new MetroDialogSettings()
        {
            AffirmativeButtonText = "Hi",
            NegativeButtonText = "Go away!",
            FirstAuxiliaryButtonText = "Cancel",
            ColorScheme = MetroDialogOptions.ColorScheme
        };

        MessageDialogResult result = await this.ShowMessageAsync("Hello!", "Welcome to the world of metro!",
            MessageDialogStyle.AffirmativeAndNegativeAndSingleAuxiliary, mySettings);

        if (result != MessageDialogResult.FirstAuxiliary)
            await this.ShowMessageAsync("Result", "You said: " + (result == MessageDialogResult.Affirmative ? mySettings.AffirmativeButtonText : mySettings.NegativeButtonText +
                Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "This dialog will follow the Use Accent setting."));
    }
```

How i could i call ShowMessageDialog from any other ViewModels and show the Dialog over that MainWindow?

Thanks!

Comment: this is possible with the latest alpha version: Using MahApps Dialog Boxes in a MVVM Setup -> http://dragablz.net/2015/05/29/using-mahapps-dialog-boxes-in-a-mvvm-setup/

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `ActiveWindow` Like so :

```
var metroWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>()
                                     .SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsActive) as MetroWindow;
```

I would suggest to make a `MessageService` that retrive the Active Window and manage all the messages of your application. Furthermore, you should Implement a interface (`IMessageService`) if you want the ability to Unit Test your code.